# Find values so that integral is a bounded operator

Tags: integration, analysis

Find all positive values $\alpha$ for which the formula

\begin{align*}
A_\alpha u(x) = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{u(y)}{(x+y)^\alpha} \,dy 
\end{align*}
defines a bounded operator in $L^1([0,1])$.  Compute its norm.

I know that this defines a bounded operator for $\alpha <1$.  What I did will not work for $\alpha \geq 1$.  I tired to use specific $L^1$ functions but its not working.  Do you have any advice on how to approach these types of problems?

\begin{align*}
||A_\alpha u(x)||_1 & = \int\limits_0^1\left| \int\limits_0^1 \frac{u(y)}{(x+y)^{\alpha}}\, dy \right|\,dx \\
& \leq \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{|u(y)|}{(x+y)^{\alpha}}\,dy\, dx \\
& \leq \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{|u(y)|}{x^{\alpha}}\,dy\, dx\\
& =\int\limits_0^1 ||u||_1 \frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}\, dx\\
\end{align*}

The integral above converges if $\alpha <1$.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Would you mind showing your work for the case $0 < \alpha < 1$?

Comment: I will add them to the question.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the edits.  I am new to this thing so I am trying to get the hang of it.

Comment: No worries :) You did a pretty good job for your first post.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider $u(x) = 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $\alpha \ge 2$. Then we have

$$A_{\alpha}u(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x+y)^{\alpha}}\,dy.$$

Letting $z = \dfrac{y}{x}$, we have $dz = \dfrac{1}{x}\,dy$ and so

$$A_{\alpha}u(x) = \int_0^{x^{-1}}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}(1+z)^{\alpha}}x\,dz = \frac{1}{x^{\alpha-1}}\int_0^{x^{-1}}\frac{1}{(1+z)^{\alpha}}\,dz.$$

The antiderivative of $(1+z)^{-\alpha}$ is $\frac{1}{-\alpha+1}(1+z)^{-\alpha+1}$. Then we get

$$A_{\alpha}u(x) = \frac{x^{-\alpha+1}}{-\alpha+1}\left((1+x^{-1})^{-\alpha+1}-1\right) = \frac{1}{-\alpha+1}\left((x+1)^{-\alpha+1}-x^{-\alpha+1}\right).$$

For such $\alpha$, this is not integrable.

Comment: The result is integrable for $\alpha=1.5$.  This function tells us that $\alpha <2$.

Comment: Oh doh. You're right. I neglected the $+1$ in the exponent. My mistake. Let me correct that. I'll update the post shortly with a more correct proof.

Comment: Thanks.  I have spent a lot of time on this problem.

Comment: I have thought about this some more and I still can't figure it out.  Please let me know if you did.

Comment: I thought I had a counter example for $1< \alpha < 2$ but it doesn't work. I have a very strong feeling that it is bounded for this range but I'm not sure how to show it. Maybe try indicator functions?